# Retrieving an XElement from Dictionary object (<string, List<XElement>>) which contains List of XElements using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a Dictionary object having a single key and List of `XElement`s (more than 380,000) . I have to retrieve the `XElement` from the list of `XElement`s based on the `XElement` value

Created Dictionary object using the following code:

```
Dictionary<string, List<XElement>> dictionaryObj = new Dictionary<string, List<XElement>>();
dictionaryObj.Add("KeyName", new List<XElement>());

dictionaryObj["KeyName"].Add(xelementObj); //this line is in a for loop using which I am adding all the XElements to Dictionary object
```

Tried following code to search for an `XElement` value

```
var input ="9879-9890-223-abc-test";

var matchingKeys = dictionaryObj
                      .Where(kvp => kvp.Value.ToString().Contains(input))
                                     .Select(kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Comment: Your value of the KVP in the dictionary is a list, not a string, so calling `ToString` on it doesn't make a lot of sense.  It's hard to tell what you're trying to do from this question, because as it appears, you are adding a bunch of elements to a list on the same key.  Can you just use linq against the list directly, or add elements to a dictionary where the key is what you are trying to search on?

Comment: Seems like you want something more like `dictionaryObj.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Value(x => x.ToString().Contains(input)))?.Value` but if you are searching for an `XElement` by value, why are you using a `Dictionary` to start with? Ideally the key should be used to help narrow down your search...

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. I have following XElements (more than 300,000).
<Tag1><Tag1_1>9879-9890-223-abc-test<Tag1_1><Tag1_2/><Tag1>
<Tag2><Tag2_1>9999-9893-111-234-444t<Tag2_1><Tag2_2/><Tag2>
I want to retrieve entire <Tag1> as Tag1_1 value is same as the value I am searching for.

Why I am going with Dictionary is, I want to store all the XElements in Dictionary so that I can retrieve it in a faster way when compared with extracting using XmlReader.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Value of the Dictionary is of type `List<XElement>` you will need to  check against the values contained in the list:

```
var matchingKeys = dictionaryObj
                   .Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Any(xElement => xElement.Value == input))
                   .Select(kvp => kvp.Value);
```

My example compares the XElement value (text content) against the input provided. Feel free to adjust as needed.

HTH

Comment: I think you're mixing things together. Your implementation isn't doing any recursive check; you're not recursing through your collection. Another thing, I'd use the string API to avoid problems when comparing strings together

Comment: @jcruz, Thank you for your response. I tried your solution but still it is returning no results.
I also tried following (xElement => xElement.Value.ToString()) but still I am getting no results.

To make my query more clear. 
I have following XElements (more than 300,000). 
<Tag1><Tag1_1>9879-9890-223-abc-test<Tag1_1><Tag1_2/><Tag1> 
<Tag2><Tag2_1>9999-9893-111-234-444t<Tag2_1><Tag2_2/><Tag2> 
After performing Linq search, I want to retrieve entire <Tag1> as Tag1_1 value is same as the value I am searching for.

Comment: @SuC what is the value of `xelementObj` when you add it to the dictionary? Here: `dictionaryObj["KeyName"].Add(xelementObj);`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for providing your inputs. With the following code, I am able to retrieve the XElement.

```
foreach (var item in dictionaryObj)
{
    var matchedXElement = item.Value.Where(x => x.Value.Contains(input));
}
```